# Filter by custom dimension value and start date

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My query includes following parameters

```
'ids': 'ga:xxxxxxxxx',
'dimensions': 'ga:date, ga:pagePath',
'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
'start-date': '2016-10-12',
'end-date': 'today',
'filters': 'ga:dimension4==123',
'sort': 'ga:date,-ga:pageviews'
```

The problem is that with **some** `dimension4` values I don't get **any** results if start date is before certain date, `end-date` stays the same.

The `start-date` before which the issue occurs varies with different `dimension4` values, and with some `dimension4` values I can put 1000daysAgo and it would still work.

---

There seems to be no relation between this error and the date when I started sending values to `dimension4`, which was on 20 Nov 2016.

The most popular problematic `start-dates` seems to around 30 Oct, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Exactly the same results in Query Explorer - https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ (no errors, though)

---

### Examples

41 Days and has results

[image: 41 Days and has results]

42 Days and no results

[image: 42 Days and no results]

Comment: I think you are going to have to show some examples of the data results.

Comment: added examples @DaImTo

Comment: I am not sure but this might be due to sampling in data. What happens if you take start date and end date both 42 days ago?

Comment: Then I will also get 0 results, but that makes sense because data collection for this value started less than 42 days ago, earliest record on Dec 2. I also tried `samplingLevel: HIGHER_PRECISION`, still the same result @dikesh

Comment: i dont understand you at all, when you implemented the CD4?  did you make any changes regarding the scope lvl? i hopes that can be the origin of the issue.

A sad new, you can't detect this change, because it's not logged on the history changes list.

I think that the platform will look always on the same scope and get confused when this changes comes over . what happens if you looked from oct 30 to backwards, it happens the same? look if exist a before and a after on that day.